# how to stop Mobile shutting down on apps using as Battery dropping from 70% to 0% in Android 6.0.1

Tags: battery, charging, reboot, adoptable-storage, shutdown

**Question:- how to stop Mobile shutting down  on apps using as  Battery dropping from 70% to 0% in  Android 6.0.1.**

I have formatted my External micro sd card as internal and  automatically while  installing apps it moves to external  sd card even Facebook and many common apps installed on micro sd card. but still many are on  internal memory.

i googled and founded that its may be battery calibration problem i tried to fully discharge battery  to 0% by restating  then again recharged it to  100% and i tried accu-battery app and many other apps for battery calibration but  problem  persisted of shutting down of phone at 70%- to 75%  while using if its kept  on standby  ie. not used it  sometimes dont shut down till 35%

From last 2-3 days  my android 6.0.1 OS mobile phone is restating even charging to 100% as its heavily used or many apps opened it just show low battery sound  in main OS window to 0% and immediately shuts down. After shutting down if i charge it on black screen it  shows 50%-75% battery remaining on keeping the charger on mobile  when i keep the charger connected  it  then never gets shut down... but the mobile back panel gets heated up drastically and on seeing in accubattery app the temperature of internal   sensor shows  battery temp  in red sign from 47 degree to 50 degree many times.

I have tried in safe mode its still shutting down ...i tried in maintenance or in boot menu mode its not shut down .... now i am confused

1. is due to  os android 6.0.1 crashing  :- (formatted -2-3 times still occurs)
2. is it due to apps moved or installed in external micro sd card crashing ( as in safe mode it works fine dont shutdown  in 36% of but apps moved installed in external card not showing in safe mode)
3. is it due to overheating of chips  or circuits
4. or its due to some particular app crashing ( i tried
   is it due to some internal or external memory card sectors became bad due to formatting 3-5 times in this week )
5. is battery life is finished is battery failing ( but its working fine in safe mode on common system apps)

solution i think:

1. I think to format external sd card to zero level or low level formatting so that it become  fresh and clear which   can be done through mini partition tool
2. I think to format internal memory sd card through adb shell fstim  or dd if
   dd if=/dev/zero of=/sdcard/filler but it doesn't make much sense on flash storage. Running fstrim  to clear unused space so that it gets refreshed and any junk saved can be freshen up

Any suggestions opinion are welcomed  kindly  give your technical  expert advice for solving the issues....

Thank you in advance for  reading answering and giving your precious time  and  precious technical advice or opinion

Comment: Based on the installed Android version it is obvious that we are talking about an older phone. On older phones it is not unusual that the battery power suddenly drops if the phone needs a bit more power (if the phone consumes more power than the battery can provide for some seconds the voltage drops). This is a clear indicator that the battery is nearly dead. The only way to fix this problem is to replace the battery as the battery will only get worse not better. You can test that by yourself by connecting the phone to a charger. While it is connected it should to go off anymore.

Comment: Thanks @Robert for the explanation! I have the very same issue on one of my devices running Android 7 – and I can confirm the shutdown always happens when something suddenly calls for "more power". Examples include (but are not restricted to): making photos with flashlight (makes photos fine without, but though at 70%+ battery shuts down with flash), track recording via GPS, playing a (streamed) video. Replacing the battery? Yeah, I'd try that if it were replaceable (it's not in the affected device unfortunately).

Comment: @Robert gr8 to see if reply brother thanks a lot for our quick reply and sharing your valuable and precious knowledge and experience ..I will surely get new battery  soon for the same but it will take 3-4 days as mobile set is old and it's not available in local market have to purchase online....Meanwhile any trick to sustain battery fro some days and. Get temporary solution so that my work don't get hamper or stopped

Comment: Either
1. battery is genuinely gone kaput
2. some app keeps running in background - try removing apps like fb, whatsapp etc and see if it persists
3. check if location and wifi are off and wifi scanning is also off